# How to set image wallpaper, when user click on Image?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to coding and never worked with it before! I am  working on wallpaper application were I created the gallery . I managed to do  this , but I want to modify the  app so that when user click on specific image It allow them to set as wallpaper. I need some help with this! (Sorry for bad English)

Does anyone know how I should do this? Really thankful for help

Following are my code...

MainActivity .java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;

public class GalleryDemoActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView selectedImageView;

    private ImageView leftArrowImageView;

    private ImageView rightArrowImageView;

    private Gallery gallery;

    private int selectedImagePosition = 0;

    private List<Drawable> drawables;

    private GalleryImageAdapter galImageAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getDrawablesList();
        setupUI();
    }

    private void setupUI() {

        selectedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selected_imageview);
        leftArrowImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left_arrow_imageview);
        rightArrowImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right_arrow_imageview);
        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

        leftArrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (selectedImagePosition > 0) {
                    --selectedImagePosition;

                }

                gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);
            }
        });

        rightArrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (selectedImagePosition < drawables.size() - 1) {
                    ++selectedImagePosition;

                }

                gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);

            }
        });

        gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                selectedImagePosition = pos;

                if (selectedImagePosition > 0 && selectedImagePosition < drawables.size() - 1) {

                    leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                    rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));

                } else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) {

                    leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));

                } else if (selectedImagePosition == drawables.size() - 1) {

                    rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));
                }

                changeBorderForSelectedImage(selectedImagePosition);
                setSelectedImage(selectedImagePosition);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });

        galImageAdapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(this, drawables);

        gallery.setAdapter(galImageAdapter);

        if (drawables.size() > 0) {

            gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);

        }

        if (drawables.size() == 1) {

            rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));
        }

    }

    private void changeBorderForSelectedImage(int selectedItemPos) {

        int count = gallery.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gallery.getChildAt(i);
            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_border));
            imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

        }

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gallery.getSelectedView();
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_image_border));
        imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    }

    private void getDrawablesList() {

        drawables = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage1));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage2));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage3));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage4));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage5));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage6));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage7));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage8));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage9));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage10));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage11));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage12));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage13));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage14));
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.natureimage15));

    }

    private void setSelectedImage(int selectedImagePosition) {

        BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) drawables.get(selectedImagePosition);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bd.getBitmap(), (int) (bd.getIntrinsicHeight() * 0.9), (int) (bd.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.7), false);
        selectedImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        selectedImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    }
}
```

GalleryAdapter. java

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity context;

    private static ImageView imageView;

    private List<Drawable> plotsImages;

    private static ViewHolder holder;

    public GalleryImageAdapter(Activity context, List<Drawable> plotsImages) {

        this.context = context;
        this.plotsImages = plotsImages;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return plotsImages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            imageView = new ImageView(this.context);

            imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

            convertView = imageView;

            holder.imageView = imageView;

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(plotsImages.get(position));

        holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 90));

        return imageView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }

}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selected_imageview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gallery_relative_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gallery_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_arrow_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left_disabled" />

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_arrow_imageview"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_arrow_imageview"
            android:spacing="20dip" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_arrow_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_enabled" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gallerydemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".GalleryDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please refer to this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783203/get-id-from-imageview-and-set-as-wallpaper-on-click

Comment: I didnt understand where should i paste the following code ?          Button buttonSetWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setwallpaper);
   buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

Comment: you need to have a button which allows the user to set that image as wallpaper on click of that button.

Comment: @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
         = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
         Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
         if(bitmap!=null)
         myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});

Comment: or you can use something like below to have click listener on your image:ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // your code here
    }
});

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without button ?

Comment: I am sorry.. But can you please tell me where should I put your imahe click listener code in my code... I am new to this.. and I learning...thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Image click listener:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
     = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
     Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
     if(bitmap!=null)
     myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
});
```

I think something like below would work in your code:

```
    gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                selectedImagePosition = pos;

                if (selectedImagePosition > 0 && selectedImagePosition < drawables.size() - 1) {

                    leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                    rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));

                } else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) {

                    leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));

                } else if (selectedImagePosition == drawables.size() - 1) {

                    rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));
                }

                changeBorderForSelectedImage(selectedImagePosition);
                setSelectedImage(selectedImagePosition);

selectedImageView .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
             = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
             Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)selectedImageView .getDrawable()).getBitmap();
             if(bitmap!=null)
             myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        });
            }
```

or something like below :

```
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                    selectedImagePosition = pos;

                    if (selectedImagePosition > 0 && selectedImagePosition < drawables.size() - 1) {

                        leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                        rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));

                    } else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) {

                        leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));

                    } else if (selectedImagePosition == drawables.size() - 1) {

                        rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));
                    }

                    changeBorderForSelectedImage(selectedImagePosition);
                    setSelectedImage(selectedImagePosition);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gallery.getSelectedView();

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                 = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                 Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                 if(bitmap!=null)
                 myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            });


         }
```

Make sure you have the below permission in your androidManifest.xml, just put it below  and above :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

For dialog to appear and wait for 3 sec to open it:

```
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                        selectedImagePosition = pos;

                        if (selectedImagePosition > 0 && selectedImagePosition < drawables.size() - 1) {

                            leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                            rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));

                        } else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) {

                            leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));

                        } else if (selectedImagePosition == drawables.size() - 1) {

                            rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));
                        }

                        changeBorderForSelectedImage(selectedImagePosition);
                        setSelectedImage(selectedImagePosition);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gallery.getSelectedView();

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     Handler handler = new Handler();
                 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GalleryDemoActivity.this);
                         myAlertDialog.setTitle("Wallpaper");
                         myAlertDialog.setMessage("Want to set as Wallpaper?");
                         myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                              WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                                 = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                                try {
                                 Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                                 if(bitmap!=null)
                                 myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                          }});
                         myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                         dialog.dismiss();
                          }});
                         myAlertDialog.create().show(); 
                    }

                 }, 3000);
                    }
                });


             }
```

Comment: i tried the above edited code.. However, it's working for some images only...whenever, I swipe to next image it dosen't pop up set wallpaper dialogue box..I mean .when I close the whole app and start again.. It doesnt popup dialogue box for setting wallpaper..

Comment: I think you need to tweak a little and see how your app is flowing, and use the wallpaper code at appropriate place. For example, when you swipe to next image, make sure it is the selected image and the flow is correct to set the wallpaper code. hope it helps.